# Page breaks and memory

Tags: page-breaking, tex-core

Note the following passage in the TeXbook (p. 110)

> TeX breaks lists of lines into pages by computing badness ratings and
>   penalties, more or less as it does when breaking paragraphs into
>   lines. But pages are made up one at a time and removed from TeX's
>   memory; there is no looking ahead to see how one page break will
>   affect the next one. In other words, TeX uses a special method to find
>   the optimum breakpoints for the lines in an entire paragraph, but it
>   doesn't attempt to find the optimum breakpoints for the pages in an
>   entire document. The computer doesn't have enough high-speed memory
>   capacity to remember the contents of several pages, so TeX simply
>   chooses each page break as best it can, by a process of "local" rather
>   than "global" optimization.

Computer memory is now a bit cheaper than in 1984. Do any of the modern distributions compute page breaks in a smarter, more memory-intensive way than plain TeX?

Comment: No, TeX the program is basically unchanged.

Comment: It's would certainly be feasible to look ahead at more pages with today's computers, but some one would still have to come up with a optimal algorithm...